# Unable to use SameSite=none with secure attribute, using Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie to create the cookie

Tags: 8, cookies

I am trying to create a cookie in Drupal 8.9 with `SameSite=none` with secure attribute, using the `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie` class but I am unable to do so as the class doesn't allow the secure attribute along with none.

Also, I tried setting the Cookie's secure parameter to `TRUE` but it results in infinite redirects in my site.  I don't want to implement the solution on site level as it will affect other cookies capabilities. I just want to do this for one particular cookie I am creating.

```php
$cookie = new Cookie(self::SIGMACOOKIENAME, TRUE, 0, '/', NULL, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, self::SAMESITE_NONE);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're setting `SameSite=None`, you'll need to set the `Secure` attribute for HTTPS.

> If `SameSite=None` is set, the cookie `Secure` attribute must also be set (or the cookie will be blocked).
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite#none

Comment: Yes, if I set the `Secure` attribute then my site results in infinite redirects.

Comment: That’s the issue then, you’ll need to fix your site to work with HTTPS. For example, with letsencrypt.